# Persian/Arabic texts are not displayed properly in dropdown populated from an Object

Tags: javascript, cordova, javascript-objects

I am populating data from an Object inside a Dropdown dynamically, but the value of Object are in Persian and inside android app it displays them as symbols like: Ø´ÛŒÙƚÚ«Ø§ÙǂÛ

And it displays Persian/Farsi fonts on other Elements without any Unicode problem.

[image]

I tried these methods, it works in Browser but not in Android:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in HTML Head and:

```
<script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
```

All failed while I launch my app on Android.

The Javascript object from which I'm populating data from is:

```
const schoolsList = {
    Kabul: {
        'دامان د هلکانو او نجونو متوسطه': { emis: '823000038', name: 'دامان د هلکانو او نجونو متوسطه', type: 'Public' },
        'ثمرخیل  د هلکانو او نجونو لیسه': { emis: '823000013', name: 'ثمرخیل  د هلکانو او نجونو لیسه', type: 'Public' },
        'شیرین دل کوچی د هلکانو او نجونو ابتدایه': { emis: '823000031', name: 'شیرین دل کوچی د هلکانو او نجونو ابتدایه', type: 'Public' },
        'بحر آباد د هلکانو او نجونو متوسطه': { emis: '823000003', name: 'بحر آباد د هلکانو او نجونو متوسطه', type: 'Public' }
}
```

};

I will be very thankful for your help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an emulator, or on a real device?

Comment: I'm using an Emulator

Comment: OK. One thing to try is to retest on a physical device. I've run into a similar issue on an emulator in my Cordova app -- lots of junk characters -- that went away when I used a "real" device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm going to try that ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file with "UTF-8 with BOM" encoding, and the problem will be solved.

VS Code:
If you are using VS Code as your code editor, at the bottom right click UTF-8, then click Save with Encoding, and then choose UTF-8 with BOM.

Sublime Text:
If you are using Sublime Text, go to File, Save with Encoding, and click UTF-8 with BOM.